# Can steam be removed from Vacuum chamber containing Salt water, and steam be turned back into water? Cost Effective?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water

I've had these questions since science class many years ago.. So if water boils at lower temperatures while under a vacuum; Is there any way we can boil Salty Ocean Water, collect the steam/vapor and then turn that into clean water.. I do not know the true science behind it and what it would take to even try it, But I strongly believe it could be an amazing idea...  Instead of using filters to remove the salt from the water or use large ammounts of fossil fuels to conventionally boil water to extract steam.. Wouldn't it take only electricity?(which is renewable energy)...

Comment: You have to use energy to pull a vacuum.

Comment: Like march stated, creating a vacuum will require energy, and the use of fuel. Even if you made a partial vacuum to reduce the boiling point, you still need energy to boil, and the energy needed to make the vacuum. Altogether, the cost of this process will be greater than traditional desalination methods.

Comment: "Wouldn't it take only electricity?(which is renewable energy)..."  Not all electricity generation is renewable.  In a lot of places, using electricity means that you're causing fossil fuel to be burnt.  The only truly renewable electricity is what you get by only turning on your equipment when there's a surplus of renewable power.

Comment: You have invented *vacuum distillation*. It is indeed one of the ways we can do desalination of sea water to produce fresh water.

Comment: You can of course also use a solar still to evaporate fresh water out of sea water, then you know for sure you are only using renewable energy.

Answer (score 0):

Water boils because it is brought into a condition where its vapor pressure is greater than it's ambient pressure.  Whether this is done by pulling a vacuum on water at ambient temperature, or raising the temperature of the water, the same amount of energy must be put into the water to boil it.

So there's no free lunch here*.  I rather suspect that it's a lot more efficient to boil water by putting it in a well-insulated container and boiling it, rather than pulling a vacuum.

Certainly, in general, it's going to be cheaper to use that electricity to just boil the water in the conventional way -- and "cheaper" in this context means fewer economic resources spent in building and maintaining the facility that does it, and at least in a loosely-coupled sense, less energy spent per gallon over the lifetime of the facility.

* That's basically the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I don't know how accurate it is but Wikipedia (piecing together several articles) says that multi stage flash distillation is the second most common method of desalination (after reverse osmosis) and is done under (partial) vacuum, so they categorize it as a form of vacuum distillation.

Comment: That's cool!  I was sticking with the physics I knew (thermodynamics rules), and not the practical applications that I don't.